# Switch statement and isset

Tags: php, switch-statement

Since a couple of months ago my website was full of notice errors so I'm trying to fix the code now. I suppose there was some php update. I'm not so bright at php so:

```
switch ( (isset($_GET['action'])) ) {

case "delete":
delete();
break;

}
```

this won't work when I add isset.

Can't you use isset inside a function?
I dont know really so I'm asking you guys that know these things.

cheers

Answer (score 6):

isset returns a bool (see the [isset manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)). Your case won't work, as 'deleted' is not a valid boolean value (it evaluates to true I think, but still).

You should check if it's set first, then switch:

```
if(isset($_GET['action')) {
  switch ( $_GET['action']) ) {
    case "delete":
      delete();
      break;
  }
} else {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That is because [`isset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) returns `true` or `false`, not a string (which is what your `case` statements expect).

Answer (score 1):

isset() returns bool (true or false). You want to call isset() before switch. Example:

```
if (isset($_GET['action']))
{
  switch($_GET['action'])
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check isset() before you go into the switch.

Answer (score 0):

> if ( isset($_GET['action'])){
>
> > ```
> >   switch($_GET['action']){
> >         case "login":
> >         $nowfile = 'pages/login.php';
> >         break;
> >     }
> > if (file_exists($nowfile)){
> >     include($nowfile);
> > }else{
> >     echo "<b>Achtung:</b> Die file $nowfile existiert nicht";
> > }
> > ```
> >
> > }